# AWS CDK - aws-cloudfront - Multiple Behaviors & Origins

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How to create multiple behaviors & origins with stable API?

There are no examples in the documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudfront-readme.html#cloudfrontwebdistribution-api-stable

Specifically, I'm interested in how to provide behavior for API Gateway.

Comment: Not sure about stable api, I assume you already saw the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudfront-readme.html#multiple-behaviors-origins) for this in experimental api?

Comment: @odenS0n, this is Experimental API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approaches is to use a custom domain name for API gateway and use it in CloudFront. Details provided here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9397